# C# how to read a text file-find/replace the text-Remove the whitespace-Then finally update a line with the count of how many were replaced

Tags: replace

I have a text file in the format of this (Each entry is on it's own line):

Begin

abc

XXX

abc

abc

XXX

End*5*

Begin

abc

XXX

End*2*

I want to read in the file and for each section find the Begin entry and remove all of the "XXX" entries and it's leftover white space up until the End.  When the removal is complete I need to update the End number to subtract for each removed "XXX" then move on to the next Begin/End block until getting to the end of the file and saving.  What is the best way to do this?  Could you please include a code sample?  Thanks for the help!

Figured it out over time :-).  See answer below.

Comment: Added below for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
        {
            StreamReader reading = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text);
            string str;
            int x = 0;
            while ((str = reading.ReadLine()) != null)
            {    
                if (str.Contains("XXX"))
                {       
                    str = str.Replace("XXX", "");
                    x++;
                }

                if (str.Contains("End*"))
                {
                    //read get the number between End*<NUMBER>*                       
                    var Match = Regex.Matches(str, @"^End*\*\d+");
                    string seCount = Match[0].Value.ToString().Remove(0,3);

                    // Get the final number to go back into End
                    int original = Int32.Parse(seCount);
                    int finalValue = original - x;

                    // Place the final value back into End Segment
                    str = str.Replace(original.ToString(), finalValue.ToString());

                    // Need to reset to zero since this is the End which is the end of the segment
                    x = 0;
                }
                if (str != "")
                {
                    write.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
            write.Close();
            resultBox.Text = "File has been cleaned\r\n";
            resultBox.AppendText("Filename= " + textBox1.Text + "modified");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```